# Caliburn Micro - is it possible to intercept calls to execute a command?

Tags: caliburn.micro

I want to add error handling to my view-models so that when a command is executed and an exception thrown, the error is handled gracefully and a modal dialog displayed.

I've got this working but my approach is a too wordy.  Errors are trapped within a command  and then published via an IObservable.  A behavior subscribes to the errors - creating an appropriate view model and passing to the WindowManager.  While it works, I'd prefer something more declarative.

Instead I want to decorate or intercept calls to commannds (bound to a button) and provide generic error handling.  The try-catch might call out to a method on the view model or command that is decorated with a Rescue attribute.

I understand this is possible within Caliburn but can it be done with Micro?  Perhaps there's an alternative approach?

Comment: http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=71 that's for CM/WPF but can probably be modified for SL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880918/caliburn-micro-recovering-from-exception-in-iresult) question I asked on SO and subsequently answered with help via the CM codeplex forum.

I slightly modified the `RescueAttribute` of [this](http://marcoamendola.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/a-caliburn-micro-recipe-filters/) CM filters implementation to allow the error handling routine to be executed as a coroutine.

This in combination with the `ShowModal` `IResult` available in some of the samples should get you what you want.